# Best way to negate every other entry of the diagonal of a matrix in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I want to create a numpy matrix that is the identity with every other diagonal entry negated. A few options are:

Ugly:

```
n = 10
i_star = np.eye(n)
for i in range(n):
    if i % 2 == 1:
        i_star[i,i] *= -1
```

Slightly better:

```
n = 10
i_star = np.eye(n)
i_star = i_star[[np.arange(1,n,2)],[np.arange(1,n,2)]] *= -1
```

Is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use `np.diag`:

```
np.diag([1,-1]*5)
```

Comment: Would this allow you to create a 9x9 matrix?

Comment: well you can put whatever you like in the argument, `[1,-1]*4+[1]` if you prefer...

Comment: Yeah, but an ideal solution wouldn't have special cases for where n is even versus odd. Otherwise, this seems like the most elegant solution.

Comment: Then @LakshayGarg's solution is probably the improvement you are after

Comment: @Julien what about np.diag(([1,-1]*n)[:n]) ?

Comment: works too, matter of taste... but you might as well `np.diag(([1,-1]*((n+1)//2)[:n])` then to avoid creating too long of a list...

Comment: I prefer mine, since creating a 1-D array and then halving it will rarely be a bottleneck and seems cleaner. Anyway, thanks again for the suggestion, I think this is the most readable solution by a long shot.

Answer (score 3):

I think so. Since the matrix is square, you can use the same index list for both the rows and columns.

```
idx = np.arange(1,n,2) 
i_star[idx,idx] = -1
```

---

Even shorter, using `np.r_`:

```
i_star[np.r_[1:n:2], np.r_[1:n:2]] = -1
```

```
print(i_star)
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0., -1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., -1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1.]])
```

Comment: Definitely an improvement, but the bounds are off by one. It should be np.arange(1, n, 2), I believe.

Comment: @JamesShapiro Thanks, appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
from itertools import cycle, islice
import numpy as np

i_star = np.diag(list(islice(cycle([1, -1]), 10)))
```